# Python configuration library

Tags: python, configuration-files

I am looking for a python configuration library that merge multiple text configuration files into single object just like json.

has anybody know a good one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote the [pymlconf](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymlconf) for this purpose.the configuration syntax is [yaml](http://www.yaml.org/).

**For example:**

*Config files:*

```
#app/conf/users/sites.mysite.conf:
name: mysite.com
owner:
   name: My Name
   phone: My Phone Number
   address: My Address


#app/conf/admin/root.conf:
server:
   version: 0.3a
sites:
   admin:
      name: admin.site.com
      owner:
         name: Admin Name
         phone: Admin Phone Number
         address: Admin Address

#app/conf/admin/server.conf:
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 80

#../other_path/../special.conf:
licence_file: /path/to/file
log_file: /path/to/file

#app/src/builtin_config.py:
_builtin_config={
   'server':{'name':'Power Server'}
}

OR:

_builtin_config="""
    server:
       name: Power Server
"""
```

*Then look at single line usage:*

```
from pymlconf import ConfigManager
from app.builtin_config import _builtin_config

config_root = ConfigManager(
   _builtin_config,
   ['app/conf/admin','app/conf/users'],
   '../other_path/../special.conf')
```

*Fetching config entries:*

```
# All from app/conf/users/sites.mysite.conf
print config_root.sites.mysite.name
print config_root.sites.mysite.owner.name
print config_root.sites.mysite.owner.address
print config_root.sites.mysite.owner.phone

# All from app/conf/admin/root.conf
print config_root.sites.admin.name
print config_root.sites.admin.owner.name
print config_root.sites.admin.owner.address
print config_root.sites.admin.owner.phone

print config_root.server.name       # from _builtin_config
print config_root.server.version    # from app/conf/admin/root.conf
print config_root.server.host       # from app/conf/admin/server.conf
print config_root.server.port       # from app/conf/admin/server.conf

print config_root.licence_file      # from ../other_path/../special.conf
print config_root.log_file          # from ../other_path/../special.conf
```

It seems this covers your problem.but you can fork it on [github](https://github.com/pylover/pymlconf)

Links:

1. [Python package index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymlconf)
2. [Source on github](https://github.com/pylover/pymlconf)
3. [Documentation](http://packages.python.org/pymlconf/)

Answer (score 5):

The standard configuration-file parser is `ConfigParser`, part of the standard Python distribution. Read all about it here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

It supports multiple files, too.

Nice and easy to use:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.cfg')

# Retrieve a variable
myvar = config.get("sectionName", "variableName", 0)
```